# How To Serve Django Applications with Apache and mod_wsgi on LXLE

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to serve web pages through Apache 2.4.18 from Django using mod_wsgi and receive error 403 Forbidden when I access local host.

**System**:
LXLE Unix
Apache 2.4.18
Django version 1.11.17
libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3i

**Procedure followed**: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04

**Symptoms:**

1. Before changing the 000-default.conf file, the default Apache page is    accessible to localhost address
2. After changing the 000-default.conf file as below, I receive error 403-Forbidden when accessing localhost address
3. If I start the Django server, the default Django page is accessible at localhost:8000

**Configuration**:
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    **#FROM HERE!!!**
    Alias /static /home/florian/django/myproject/myproject/static
    <Directory /home/florian/django/myproject/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/florian/django/myproject/myproject/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
           Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/florian/django/myproject python-home=/home/florian/django/myproject/myprojectenv
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/florian/django/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py


</VirtualHost>
```

**Error log Apache:**

> ```
> (myprojectenv) florian@desktop:~/django/myproject/myproject$ tail -n 10 /var/log/apache2/error.log
> [Sun Dec 16 09:35:25.721695 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 10317:tid 140256502339328] [client 127.0.0.1:54346] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/florian/django/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
> [Sun Dec 16 09:44:33.817490 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 10316:tid 140256510732032] [client 127.0.0.1:54504] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/florian/django/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
> [Sun Dec 16 09:45:07.820025 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 10316:tid 140256451983104] [client 127.0.0.1:54516] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/florian/django/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
> [Sun Dec 16 09:52:32.657271 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10313:tid 140256727914368] AH00494: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
> [Sun Dec 16 09:52:32.718483 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 10313:tid 140256727914368] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
> [Sun Dec 16 09:52:32.718498 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 10313:tid 140256727914368] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
> [Sun Dec 16 09:52:32.720846 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10313:tid 140256727914368] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
> [Sun Dec 16 09:52:32.720930 2018] [core:notice] [pid 10313:tid 140256727914368] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
> [Sun Dec 16 09:53:50.049998 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 10925:tid 140256630511360] [client 127.0.0.1:54568] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/florian/django/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
> (myprojectenv) florian@desktop:~/django/myproject/myproject$
> ```

Comment: `Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message` check that the ServerName is correctly set. Again, what is the content of your ALLOWED_HOSTS?

Comment: In Django settings ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

Comment: I already identified and corrected an error in my Apache config: The path to WSGI was incorrect: <Directory /home/florian/django/myproject/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
       Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Comment: After I corrected the path to WSGI, the error has changed: florian@desktop:~$ tail -n 5 /var/log/apache2/error.log #citeste log erori

[wsgi:error] [pid 3960:tid 140035682776832] [remote 127.0.0.1:40593]   File "/home/florian/django/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[wsgi:error] [pid 3960:tid 140035682776832] [remote 127.0.0.1:40593]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[wsgi:error] [pid 3960:tid 140035682776832] [remote 127.0.0.1:40593] ImportError: No module named 'django'
florian@desktop:~$

Comment: You may want to include the new error in the question and formate appropriately so that it is readable

Comment: You should also add the `WSGIPythonHome` and `WSGIPythonPath` to correctly point to your virtualenv. Check this page in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specified any ServerName in your apache config:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Also check that you specified any `allowed_host` in your `settings.py`.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```